# Send the form fields data from payment method step in the checkout Page to a model without saving data in the database

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, model

I am a beginner to Magento, I want to send the **form fields data** from **payment method step** in the onepage checkout Page to a model **without saving data in the database**.

Please find the below screenshot
[image]

Magento : 1.9.2.0

I want to get the data in the following file: **app/code/community/PayUbiz/PayUbiz/Model/Standard.php** with method name : **getStandardCheckoutFormFields()**

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an observer in your module to listen the following observers

`sales_quote_payment_import_data_before` or `sales_order_payment_save_before`

Use `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('field_name_here')` this code for get the params.

use any of them and do your stuff there.

Comment: I want to get the  data in the following file: app/code/community/PayUbiz/PayUbiz/Model/Standard.php with method name : getStandardCheckoutFormFields

Comment: I have created the observer in the payment module still I am not getting the data.